# Altering custom taxonomy urls in Wordpress Yoast XML sitemap

Tags: php, wordpress, sitemap, yoast

I am trying to alter the url structure in the standard sitemap page produced by YOAST SEO plugin in Wordpress. I am able to alter Custom Post type sitemap using the below code, but I am not able to do it for a custom taxonomy page I have, In the if statement I used is_tax( 'city' ) but this did not work. Hotel is a custom post type and city is a custom taxonomy page that list hotels in a specific city.

```
function sitemap_post_url( $url, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type === 'hotel' ) {
        return \str_replace( 'hotel', 'test', $url );
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_url', 'sitemap_post_url', 10, 2 );
```

I really appreciate if someone can help with the code I can use in the if condition to alter custom taxonomy archive links pages in YOAST xml sitemap

Answer (score 0):

You can try with wpseo_sitemap_entry:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_entry', function ($url, $type, $term){

    if ($term->taxonomy == 'city') {
        // Do your stuff
    }


    return $url;

}, 10, 3 );
```